# How to I remove the too many arguments error for the If AND function?

Tags: if-statement, powerbi

We have job numbers most with a leading 1, with 7 digits to follow. There is one set, that leads with a 6, and is 6 digits. I need a leading '0' on both

The below formula captures the '0', for job numbers leading with a 1, with 7 digits, but not the items leading with a 6, with 6 digits:

```
Z Sage ID = IF(LEFT('Sales 
Force_Contract'[Account_Number__c],1)="1",CONCATENATE("0",'Sales 
Force_Contract'[Account_Number__c]),'Sales Force_Contract'[Account_Number__c])
```

Here's what I tried, and received this error:

```
Z Sage ID = IF(LEFT('Sales 
Force_Contract'[Account_Number__c],1)="1",IF(and('Sales 
Force_Contract'[Account_Number__c]="6",CONCATENATE("0",'Sales 
Force_Contract'[Account_Number__c]),'Sales Force_Contract'[Account_Number__c])))
```

> 'Too many arguments were passed to the AND function. The maximum
> argument count for the function is 2.'

Can you help get on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use operators that don't require you to add words like AND()
Read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/dax-operator-reference).

The following code should work:

```
Z Sage ID = 
IF (
    LEFT('Sales Force_Contract'[Account_Number__c],1) = "1" ||
    LEFT('Sales Force_Contract'[Account_Number__c],1) = "6",
    "0" & 'Sales Force_Contract'[Account_Number__c],
    'Sales Force_Contract'[Account_Number__c]
   )
```

How it works:

- It checks if the left number is either a 1 or (Or = ||) a 6.
- If yes, it adds a leading 0 (One & (&) to concatenate, two & (&&) to get the AND() function)
- If no, it takes the original account number.

Comment: Max - Thank YOU so much! This worked. And your explanation behind why makes sense. I was missing the 2nd 'left' telling the function what to do. Also, knowing the & is the concatenate, is also a twist I didn't know about! Thanks so much!